# How do I group integers in a Ruby array so that I can compress the array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, compression

Assuming I have an array of integers in `Ruby 2.1+` such as:

```
[2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

What I would like to do is compress the array so that I get something like:

```
[2, [4, 2], 1, 6, 7, [5, 8]]
```

Notice the two internal arrays just contain two elements.  The value and the number of times it is repeated.

Also, the order is important.

**EDIT*

Sorry, I didn't mention that for single elements, I'm not concerned with the count.  So `[2,1]...[1,1],[6,1]...` doesn't concern me.

In fact, I'm really only interested in groups that have 4 or more repeating integers but I didn't want to confuse the issue.  So `[3,2]` could be left as `3,3` but `[3,4]` would be used instead of `3,3,3,3` but this isn't important for the topic of the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it not `[[2, 1], [4, 2], [1, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [5, 8]]`? If your answer is that leaving a single element `2` as is is more compact than `[2, 1]`, then what makes `[4, 2]` more compact than having two elements of `4` as in `..., 4, 4, ...`?

Comment: Because I'm only interested in putting the count in repeating integers.  Sort of a "hybrid RLE".  The compressed array is eventually going to another method that will inject a special byte code that will indicate a repeating array or not.  As for your other question, the data I will be compressing contains massive amounts of repeating characters ([5, 99], etc.).  Plus, this method avoids bloating an array if pure RLE is used.  Such as compressing a checkerboard pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ruby 2.2:

```
[2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
.slice_when(&:!=)
.map{|a| a.length == 1 ? a.first : [a.first, a.length]}
# => [2, [4, 2], 1, 6, 7, [5, 8]]
```

For older Ruby:

```
[2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
.chunk{|e| e}
.map{|e, a| a.length == 1 ? e : [e, a.length]}
# => [2, [4, 2], 1, 6, 7, [5, 8]]
```

Comment: Oh that's sweet.  But I don't understand it.  lol.   Looks like some Ruby voodoo.  I should be able to upgrade to 2.2 I guess.  :-)

Comment: Yes.. You should... What is _vodoooo_ ? :-)

Comment: Don't see 2.2 for Windows (Ruby Installer).  Ugh.  Wonder if there is another way?

Comment: That worked like a treat.  However, it complained about "itself" so I changed it to:  `bytes.chunk(&:to_i).map{|_, a| a.length == 1 ? a.first : [a.first, a.length]}` and it worked for the array I have.  Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed you are making good use of the new 2.2 methods.  The two you use here seem especially helpful. Good to inform readers also. (#2 was  [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself), which sawa removed because he couldn't say it worked for "older Ruby".)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actually, I am not fully satisfied with `slice_when`. I think it would be more convenient if there were a negative version of it. Then, I can do `the_negative_method(&:itself)`.

Answer (score 0):

not as efficient as the others, but oh well.

**EDIT:** as commented below, this is an example of how **not** to do this.
Ruby has an amazing library of methods built into the Array class, and it should be utilized instead of using indices.

```
arr = [2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
tempArr = []
newArr = []
for i in 0..(arr.length - 1)
    if arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i] != arr[i - 1]
        tempArr = [arr[i], 1]
    elsif tempArr[0] == arr[i]
        tempArr[1] += 1
        if arr[i - 1] == arr[i] && arr[i + 1] != tempArr[0]
            newArr.push(tempArr)
        end
    elsif arr[i] != tempArr[0]
        newArr.push(arr[i])
        if tempArr[0] != nil
            tempArr = []
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Russell, this is very un-Ruby-like code.  You needn't be ashamed, as everybody coming to Ruby from languages that make heavy use of indices have to rid themselves of quite a bit of baggage.  However, to write Ruby like this just reinforces bad (Ruby) habits.  When you are inclined to write  `arr[i] != arr[i - 1]`, 99% percent of the time there will be a better way to do it using enumerators and blocks.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Ruby was my first programming language, but as I found projects to keep myself busy, I needed other languages. This is indeed very un-Ruby-like, and comes from my own bad habits. If anything, this is (as you pointed out) a very good example of what **not** to do.