# How do I explode an internal array in Ruby if the internal count is less than a certain value?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Using Ruby `2.1`, if I have an array like:

```
[[1,1], [2,3], [5,8], [6, 4]]
```

How can I convert that to an array that only has internal arrays with a count > 3?

For example, it should be:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, [5,8], [6,4]]
```

So `[5,8]` and `[6,4]` would "pass" because their counts are > 3 but `[1,1]` and `[2,3]` would "fail" and explode out because their counts are < than 4.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I wasn't very clear.  By "counts" I mean the second value in the internal arrays.  For example, the `[2,3]` would have a value of 2 and a count of 3.  `[5,8]` would have a value of 5 and a count of 8.

So if the count is > 3 then keep the original array.  If the count is 3 or less, then explode the value out `count` number of times.

Comment: Curious as to why I got a down vote?

Comment: It wasn't me down-voting, but it's almost certainly because your question is very ambiguous. It's not at all clear what exactly you're after.

Comment: What is your definition of *counts*?

Comment: You need to clarify your question by editing it, rather than attempting to do so in comments (as not everyone reads all comments).  I'm guessing that the elements of your array are always tuples, where the second element of each tuple is the "count".  If so, you need to say something like that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "....then explode the value out count number of times." Do you mean that `[[1,1],  [[1,1]], [[[2,3]]]],[5,8]]` should become `[1,1,[1,1],2,3,[5,8]]`?

Comment: If your purpose is to do what you wanted to do in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242520/how-do-i-group-integers-in-a-ruby-array-so-that-i-can-compress-the-array) via my answer, then you can do it directly with a little modification to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure someone can come up with a better way of doing this, but:

```
input = [[1,1], [2,3], [5,8], [6, 4]]
input.flat_map {|val, ct| ct > 3 ? [[val, ct]] : Array.new(ct, val) }
# => [1, 2, 2, 2, [5, 8], [6, 4]]
```

The basic idea is that we just map the inputs (each entry) to an output (the original entry or an exploded list of values) by the count. I'm using `flat_map` here, but you could use the same technique with `map {}.flatten(1)` if you wanted. You could also use `inject` or `each_with_object` to collect the output values, which may be more straightforward but slightly less terse.

Comment: This was exactly it.  Thanks!!  I didn't know about the flat_map.  Been a while since I've used Ruby.  :-)

Comment: `flat_map` is synonymous with `map {}.flatten(1)`, FWIW.

Comment: On reflection, I prefer `Array.new(ct, val)` to `[val]*ct`, which both @7stud and I used.  I think the former reads slightly better.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, One liners don't read well anyway--the point is to make the reader's head spin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = [[1,1], [2,3], [5,8], [6, 4]]

results = []

data.each do |arr|
  val, count = arr

  if count > 3
    results << arr
  else
    results.concat [val] * count
  end
end

p results


--output:--
[1, 2, 2, 2, [5, 8], [6, 4]]
```

Comment: That isn't the correct output.  The output should be `[1, 2, 2, 2, [5,8], [6,4]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[1,1], [2,3], [5,8], [6, 4]]

arr.flat_map { |a| (a.last > 3) ? [a] : [a.first]*a.last }
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 2, [5, 8], [6, 4]]
```

Thanks to @ChrisHeald for pointing out that `flat_map` is equivalent to `map {}.flatten(1)` (I previously had the latter) and to @7stud for telling me my original solution was incorrect, which gave me the opportunity to make my solution more interesting as well as (hopefully) correct.

Comment: What?  No `Array.new()`?  And, it's not the right output.  See my code for an explanation.  :)

Comment: @stud, I see you were speaking from experience about my output being incorrect. :-). Also, I see we both used `[a]*b`.